# Removing row and column of matrix after looking for a value (C)

Tags: c, matrix, row

I made [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518371/c-getting-the-3-minimum-elements-of-an-row-in-a-matrix-and-choose-one-randoml) some hours ago but I get myself in a mess on what I had to do after finishing what I was asking on that question. All the solutions that the people gave me were ok, but useless for what I was really looking for as I didn't wrote the question as it has to be. I've to save an important position of a value, and it wasn't necessary to be saved on the other question to solve the problem. So here's the proper one.

(everything's is explained with an example above, understanding it is easy) I've a 8x8 matrix, and after choosing the row I desire, I want to get the three minimum elements of it, and choose one of this three randomly. Then, remove the row and column that contains this number. The thing is that I'dont know how to handle those three elements and remove the columns/rows. I just know how to get the minimum element, that is the following code.

```
int pieza[ROWS][COLS] = {
0, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1,
0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0,
0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2,
0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 7,
8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1,
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 4,
0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

int myrow = 3; // the row I want to analyze
int index;
int min=0;

for (index=0;index<8;index++) {
    printf("%d", piezas[myrow][index] );
    if(piezas[myrow][index]<min)
        min=piezas[myrow][index];
    printf("\t\t");
}
printf("min: %d", min);
```

This is what I want to do. If the initial matrix is (which is always a `nxn` matrix):

```
{
0, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1,
0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0,
0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2,
0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 7,
8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1,
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 4,
0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};
```

And I choose row number 3:

```
0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

The algorithm must choose the three minimum elements of that row.

```
0, 1, 1
```

And choose randomly one of these three. If, for example, it choose the first 'one'...

```
0, **1**, 1
```

... the algorithm must go to the 3th column of that line (becaue that was the position that was that '1') and remove the row and column, so the output matrix will be as follows, one dimension less than the original matrix (beucase you have removed a row and a column):

```
    {
    0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1,
    0, 4, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0,
    0, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2,
    2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 7,
    8, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1,
    1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 4,
    0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };
```

I only know how to arrive to the line, but I'm having problems to handle three minimums because I'm having tons of problems pointers and I'm not a lot into C. 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Your final matrix (desired output) doesn't make sense, you can't have a matrix that is declared as `[8][8]` and just provide initializers for a 7x7 matrix. The fact that you put a line break after 7 elements means nothing to the C compiler, it will give you an 8x8 matrix since that's what you ask for.

Comment: My fault. If you give a `nxn` matrix, the output matrix has to be `n-1 x n-1` matrix. One dimension less. The post is edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example to be sorted with the number of column.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pair {
    int value, column;
} Pair;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    Pair *pa = (Pair *)a;
    Pair *pb = (Pair *)b;
    return pa->value - pb->value;
}

int main(void){
    int data[8] = {0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    Pair data_pair[8];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;++i){
        data_pair[i].value = data[i];
        data_pair[i].column = i;
    }
    qsort(data_pair, 8, sizeof(Pair), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("value = %d, column = %d\n", data_pair[i].value, data_pair[i].column);
    return 0; 
}
/* result
value = 0, column = 0
value = 1, column = 2
value = 1, column = 4
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much BLUEPIXY.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 8

void delrow(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int row){
    if(row < SIZE - 1)
        memmove(&a[row], &a[row+1], (SIZE*SIZE - SIZE*(row+1))*sizeof(int));
};
void delcol(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int col){
    int r;
    if(col < SIZE - 1){
        for(r=0;r<SIZE;++r){
            memmove(&a[r][col], &a[r][col+1], (SIZE - (col+1))*sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int piezas[8][8] = {
        0, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1,
        0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0,
        0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2,
        0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
        2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 7,
        8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 4,
        0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };
    //test
    int row = 8, col = 8;
    int r,c;
    delrow(piezas, 3);
    row -= 1;
    for(r=0;r<row;++r){
        for(c=0;c<col;++c)
            printf("%2d", piezas[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    delcol(piezas, 1);
    col -= 1;
    for(r=0;r<row;++r){
        for(c=0;c<col;++c)
            printf("%2d", piezas[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
/* result
 0 2 2 5 3 2 1 1
 0 4 5 2 4 3 0 0
 0 4 2 2 1 2 3 2
 2 5 6 5 3 1 2 7
 8 2 0 0 0 2 1 1
 1 2 2 1 1 6 3 4
 0 1 3 2 0 0 0 0

 0 2 5 3 2 1 1
 0 5 2 4 3 0 0
 0 2 2 1 2 3 2
 2 6 5 3 1 2 7
 8 0 0 0 2 1 1
 1 2 1 1 6 3 4
 0 3 2 0 0 0 0
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that only removes a column and not a row.
The thing is that before arriving to remove the row and column, I'm having problems to locate the value as you can read in the post.

Comment: @Borja your data seems to have been changed, but I think as there is no problem with my program. your example remove 2nd colomn.

Comment: I just put the matrix on a `nxn`format. Your input matrix has 7 rows and your output matrix has also 7 rows, and the output matrix has to have one row less, like the column, because you've to remove both, and you're removing only a column. Check the example of the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Borja And I was already fixed, Input is a matter of you one way or the other.

Comment: Got it, works now. Can you please give me any ideas on how to do all the stuff I've to do before removing the row and column? I need help with the part of getting the three minimum and choosing one randomly. Thanks.

Comment: @Borja I think the answer had been with in the previous question it.

Comment: the problem with the other answer is that they are using another auxiliar array to save the values, sort them and get the three minumum. I can't use that because I've to save the position of the value to remove the row and column that contains the choosen random value.

Comment: @Borja  Oh I see. It must be prepared to save the column as an array for selecting 3 minimum value. E.g. `struct pair { int value , column }; struct pair min[3];` //replace `int min[3];` And a stable sort is required if you want to sort.

Comment: May not require stable sort and consideration it because I be chosen at random after all.

Comment: Can you please give me more hints or at least tell me how to start coding that part? I'm not a lot into structs in C... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Borja a simple example up to another answer .

Answer (score 0):

Below is extract to get a nth smallest element from a selected row -Your first requirement before removing a row and column.

1. Copy the row
2. Sort the copied row (save index too while sorting)
3. Sorted index represents position of value in sorted order
4. pick 0 th or 1st or nth min indexing the sorted index.

------------ Very Draft code ---- try optimize -------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<memory.h>

void sortIndex(int *array, int *arrayIdx)
{
 int i=0,j=0;
 int temp=0;

 int tempArr[4];

 memcpy(tempArr, array, 4*sizeof(int));
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  printf("%d ",tempArr[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)
    {
      if(tempArr[i]>tempArr[j])
      {
       temp = arrayIdx[i];
       arrayIdx[i]=arrayIdx[j];
       arrayIdx[j]=temp;

       temp = tempArr[i];
       tempArr[i]=tempArr[j];
       tempArr[j]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
 printf("Sorted array Index\n");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  printf("%d ",arrayIdx[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 printf("Sorted array Value\n");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  printf("%d ",array[arrayIdx[i]]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}


int main ()
{
 int array[4][4] = {{4,3,2,1},{7,5,4,3},{6,5,4,4},{5,5,2,1}};
 int sortedIdx[4] = {0,1,2,3};
 int i,ii;

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
   for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
      printf("%d ",array[i][ii]);
   printf("\n");
 }

 printf("(Note:Count from 0). Which Row : ");
 scanf("%d",&i);
 sortIndex(array[i],sortedIdx);

 printf("\n");

 printf("(Nth smallest value)Give a N value (0 to 3): ");
 scanf("%d",&ii);
 printf(" (%d)  smallest value in row (%d) is (%d)\n",ii,i,array[i][sortedIdx[ii]]);

 printf("Now call function to remove Row (%d) and column (%d)\n",i,sortedIdx[ii]);

 return 0;
}
```